# AWS S3 Download iOS - The request timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nsurlsession

I'm downloading around 400 files asynchronously in my iOS app using Swift from my bucket in Amazon S3, but sometimes i get this error for several of these files. The maximum file size is around 4 MBs, and the minimum is few KBs

> Error is Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000451190 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/folder/file.html, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/folder/file.html, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase timeout:

```
let urlconfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300 // 300 seconds
```